# (Repeated) Cross-Validation and Wilcoxon test

Tags: cross-validation, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Is it a common practice to apply the Wilcoxon test to the (repeated) cross-validation score estimates when comparing two different models? I've read that most of the time the average of the cross-validation scores is taken and the model with the best average is chosen, but some authors ([here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_test_should_be_used_to_compare_k-fold_cross_validation_results), [here](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v7/demsar06a.html) and [here](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/code2.html)) suggest to apply the Wilcoxon test in order to determine if there is a statistically significant difference between the models.